# angular one-time binding syntax gives blank output

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

trying to use one-time binding syntax to my angular output but it does not work when i put :: with vm.doctors.

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}');

<li ng-repeat="item in ::vm.doctors">
    {[ ::item.name ]}
</li>
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: *** {{ ::item.name }}

Comment: I have set $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{['); $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}');

Comment: Where do you get `vm.doctors` from? Is it ready in memory when controller/directive is instantiated? Or is it taken from some API?

Comment: @Episodex it's taken from controller via $http.get...api

Comment: Can it be that you set initially `vm.doctors = [];` and one-time binding gets this as final value? This would explain not updating the values when `$http.get` finishes, which is in totally different digest cycle after variable is stabilized. Then setting this variable in `get` callback for the first time should solve the issue. If not then posting your controller's code would help much.

Comment: @Episodex yeah it's outside set like vm.doctors = []; so the solution would be to put if within .then(function...which works as I can see. how much will this influence the speed, say if 15 records are returned per page/loadmore ?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing one-time binding when you're collection can change during lifetime of the page. Leave one time binding only on item. Not on collection. (I'll put my comment in answer if it worked - to keep things clean.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be that you set initially `vm.doctors = [];` and one-time binding gets this as final value? This would explain not updating the values when `$http.get` finishes, which is in totally different digest cycle after variable is stabilized. Then setting this variable in `get` callback for the first time should solve the issue.

If you allow further updates of collection (like loading more items on scroll), don't set one-time binding on the collection, but only on items.

Comment: ok so if paging or loading is involved I should set it only on item which makes sense. how much benefit will it be in terms of speed ?

Comment: Unless you display very big amounts of items it won't be big difference. One time binding prevents Angular from setting permanent watch on `item.name` (one for each item). It will make each digest cycle bit faster. For this single property it won't be noticeable but if this list grows bigger in terms of number of properties from `item` used then using all one-time bindings can make a difference that is visible (especially if there is a lot of rows displayed). Still it will be probably like 100 ms difference :).

Comment: it will be like 15 items or so x 15rows per page, hence I will test it, thanks